# Does Bootstrap Have a Real Modal Window?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Does Bootstrap have a real modal window as in an analogue to "alert()" in which the user must respond in the browser (not just in the tab or window) before proceeding with any change?

Comment: You can set the `backdrop` and `keyboard` properties of the modal to `false`and write your logic for the question

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: What you want is to completly block the browser right? Like that the user can't change the tab, go to another page, click the backward/forward buttons? If it is that, you can't achive this with bootstrap modal

Comment: @sabotero, I do want this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.
You can set the `backdrop` and `keyboard` properties of the modal to `false` and have to write your logic for the question/answer you want.

Setting the `backdrop` and `keyboard` properties to `false` prevent the user to continue with any change in the page, but not prevent it to use the browser itself (like entering a new url in the address bar, or clicking the history buttons...).

Answer (score 2):

Here a sample code [fiddle](http://bootply.com/95158), just try

**HTML**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true })
```